# Naming Multiple Variables In A Loop

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

first time asking a question on here. I am trying to make multiple variables in Mathematica which all have the same name except for the number after it. For example, if the list I am using has 7 members, it will make the variables: member1, member2, member3, member4, and so on. If this is unclear I left an example below of how I wished it would work. Hopefully it is an easy solution!

```
list = {1,2,3,4,5}

For[i = 1, i < 6, i++,
member[i] = list[i]
]
```

Comment: This question would be more suitable for mathematica.stackexchange. Does https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/36886/table-of-variables not answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
list = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
For[i = 1, i < 6, i++,
  ToExpression["member"<>ToString[i]<>"="<>ToString[list[[i]]]]]
```

followed by

```
?member3
```

which should show you that member3 has been assigned a value of 3

This is creating a string and then evaluating it as a line of code.

Comment: If `list = {1, 2, "3", 4, 5}` this method will set not preserve the string type.

Comment: @ChrisDengen I agree completely with your comment, if you change what was asked for then you often have to change the answer. There are almost always a dozen different ways of doing anything in Mathematica, at least several of which will make little or no sense at all to a new user asking very simple questions..

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Symbol` with `Evaluate`.

```
list = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

For[i = 1, i < 6, i++,
 Evaluate[Symbol["member" <> ToString[i]]] = list[[i]]
]

member3
```

> 3

Alternatively, using `Array` instead of `For`.

```
Array[(Evaluate[Symbol["member" <> ToString[#]]] = list[[#]]) &, Length[list]]
```

And a version that clears pre-existing values.

```
Array[(With[{x = "member" <> ToString[#]},
    Clear[x];
    Evaluate[Symbol[x]] = list[[#]]]) &, Length[list]]
```